# Facebook - Page Insights via API on external website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I've seen many places talk about how to get page insights from within a facebook application. I am trying to show user's page's insights on my websites with my graphing tools **without an application**.

I can have them provide login information, or if I need to connect my website with them, etc. etc., I can do that. Does anyone know how I would go about getting this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the read_insights permission.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Your flow would be to ask the user to connect to your app and ask for the read_insights permission. Once you have the access token, you can query the data of their domains/pages/apps.

Comment: Edited the post, I don't want to make an application.

Comment: You can't without creating an application. An application is as simple as registering for an application id. This doesn't mean you need to use a facebook canvas app, any website that integrates facebook connect / graph api has a FB app id. What's your hangup with creating an app?

Comment: @ Jeff -- Needed to know if it was possible. No where, directly, have I had that answer (thank you). I had already written 8 applications and simply wanted to avoid writing one more -- writing one now. Thanks!

Comment: You can probably use one of your existing app_ids instead of making a new one.  Just ask for the additional permission.

Comment: @JeffSherlock Hi Jeff, I know that this platform is for troubleshooting but, as I am new to this field I want to make an application by which I can show the user's likes counts and share counts of his FB page. May you suggest any tutorial or sample for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for the offline_access permission too, that will allow you to update the insights without having to wait for the user to log-in.